# Retrieve the previous page title for shortcode usage

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve the previous page title with PHP and use it as a Wordpress shortcode. I have come this far with the shortcode, but I don't know how to retrieve the page title from the previous page with PHP. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
// [previous page title]
function previous_page_title( $atts ){
    $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
    return $prevPost;
}
add_shortcode( 'previous page title', 'previous_page_title' );
```

Comment: you want to get only title not URL?

Comment: Yes, only the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I did some more research with the new knowlege I had and came up with the following which does the job!! :) :)

```
// [previous page title]
function previous_page_title(){
    $previouspage = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $previouspage = str_replace('-', ' ', $previouspage);
    return basename($previouspage['path']);
}
add_shortcode( 'previous-page', 'previous_page_title' );
```

This code returns the previous page title in lowercase.

If you want the first letter to be a capital, just use the following CSS:

```
span.yourClass{
    display: inline-block;
}
span.yourClass:first-letter{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

For the record: the code above generates a shortcode called [previous-page]. You can use this shortcode to return the previous page title in a post, page or another place.

Thanks guys!